# Proof that rescaled eigenvector shares same eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\boldsymbol{v}$ is the eigenvector of $\boldsymbol{A}$, with eigenvalue $\lambda$, how can I prove that $s\boldsymbol{v}$ has the same eigenvalue $\lambda$? $s\in\mathbb{R},s\neq0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ you know that $Av = \lambda v$.

And $A$ is linear. So what is $A(sv)$ ?

Comment: wow, don't know why I did not see that

Answer (score 0):

Since $\vec{v}$ is the eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ for $s\neq 0$ we have

$A(s\vec{v})=sA(\vec{v})=s(\lambda \vec{v})=\lambda(s\vec{v})$.

Thus $s\vec{v}$ has the same eigenvalue.